# How to solve the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,3)}\frac{\sin(x)+2}{(x^2-y^2+5)^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I solve the following limit or prove that the limit does not exist in $\Bbb R$:

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,3)}\frac{\sin(x)+2}{(x^2-y^2+5)^2}?
$$

I tried to prove the limit does not exist with $y=3x/2$, $y=x+1$, but it looks like a dead end.

Comment: It does not exist in the sense that the limit isn't a real number, but you can show it tends to infinity (as the numerator stays bounded, but non-zero and positive, and the denominator tends to $0$, but positive).

Comment: The limit is of the form $\frac{\sin 2 + 2}{0}$ so it clearly diverges to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since $-1 \le \sin x \le 1$, we have:
$$\frac{1}{\left(x^2-y^2+5\right)^2} \le \frac{\sin x +2}{\left(x^2-y^2+5\right)^2} \le \frac{3}{\left(x^2-y^2+5\right)^2}$$
And the denominator clearly tends to $0$ (but stays positive) when $(x,y) \to (2,3)$, so...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The denominator goes always (no matter how you choose $y$ and $x$) to $0$ and the numerator goes to a number different than $0$, since $\sin(x)\in [-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

- $\sin(x)+2\to\sin 2 +2>0$
- $(x^2-y^2+5)^2\to0^+$